# Roasting this beef

Tags: beef, roasting

I have a 10.95 lb "round sirloin tip knuckle," USDA Select, half of which I want to roast in a conventional electric oven.

As few online recipes have this specificity (especially for this grade, cut, and technique), I have some questions:

1. How should I season it? I'm obsessed with butter, tomato, pepper, and onion.

   1. OO/butter on top?
   2. Caramelized onions?
   3. Tomato? paste?
2. Should I put aluminum foil on it when roasting it?
3. Can you give me an estimate of time/temperature?

Thanks.

Comment: See:  http://eatsandmeats.com/2012/03/11/cuts-of-beef-the-sirloin-tip/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cut would benefit from a relatively slow roast. I would thickly slice a few onions and put them in a dutch oven. Then rub the beef with mustard, salt and pepper, place on the onions, cover with a damp piece of baking parchment, put the lid on and roast at about 340F for 4 hours.

The fat will render out of the meat and the onions will caramelise beautifully in it. The meat should be fork tender and delicious.

Comment: Thanks! I might not have a dutch oven, though. Could a Pyrex tray + aluminum foil work as well?

Comment: One more thing: I just changed my plans to cook the entire 10.95lb. How much more time should it take?

Comment: Provided the tray is relatively high sided and the foil is nice and tight, it should be fine. Foil is never perfect though, so you may want to check it a couple of times during cooking and add a splash of water to stop it drying out. I'd probably give an 11lb piece, say, 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

USDA select is unfortunately the lowest grade that is commercially sold, so it's not going to be tender or well-marbled. The best option for you is to braise it in a covered pot with some liquid for about 3-4 hours at maybe 250F.